# m $\in \Bbb N$ so that $\lim_{m+n \to \infty} x_n = a$. Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n}=a$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be a sequence in real numbers and **a**$\in \Bbb R$. If exists **m** $\in \Bbb N$ so that $lim_{m+n \to \infty} x_n = a$.
Prove that $lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n}=a$

It is a problem that, I think it involves the definition of a limit as $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists N \in \Bbb N / |x_n-a|< \epsilon, \forall n\ge N $ is the same as $lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=a$
An answer using this definition would be appreciated, as I have tried to find a moment N so that it becomes true.

Comment: $\lim_{m+n\to\infty}x_n = \lim_{k\to\infty}x_{k-m}$.

Answer (score 2):

Given $$ \lim_{m+n \to \infty}x_{n}=a $$
$$ \implies \forall \epsilon >0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} ~ \text{s.t}~ |x_{n}-a|< \epsilon ~ \text{for} ~ m+n \ge N. $$
$$ \text{Choose}~ M=N-m, ~ \text{then} ~ \forall \epsilon >0, \exists M \in \mathbb{N} ~ \text{s.t} ~ |x_{n}-a|< \epsilon ~ \text{for} ~ n \ge M. $$
$$ \text{Therefore,} ~ \lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n}=a $$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the definition it enough to replace $N$ by $N+m$ but the idea is that you only care when $n$ is large, so it doesn't matter if you "drop" the first $m$ terms of the sequence, (the limit won't change).